# How to config to include Compass in Angular cli

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, compass

How to config to enable Compass in Angular cli?

I've tried to search all over the place and have no idea. It seems like Angular cli no longer include Compass by default. I'm newbie in Angular Cli and Webpeck so can anyone help with answer or provide reference to how to include Compass in Angular Cli?

Comment: Can you please provide how you were able to get it working? I am a little confused.

Comment: @SaadFarooq you need to install compass-mixins by `npm install compass-mixins` and in scss file you need to import compass by `@import ~compass-mixins/lib/compass` Good luck !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular-cli supports sass compilation out of the box, see [css-preprocessor-integration](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#css-preprocessor-integration).

You'll need to install compass sass files, for example package `compass-mixins`.

Comment: Thank you :) it works! anyways I have to import compass in scss file like this `@import ~compass-mixins/lib/compass"`; it should just `@import compass` ? (I tried it but it fail maybe I need to config somewhere? or I need to import it the first way) @kermsky